# C# How can I used a string to reference a pre-existing variable by the same name?

Tags: c#, string, reference, input

I have a textfile and on each line is a single word followed by specific values

For example:

```
texture_menu_label_1 = 0 0 512 512
```

What I want to do is read that text in and basically convert it to the following commmand:

```
texture_menu_label_1 = new int[]{0, 0, 512, 512};
```

Parsing the line and extracting the integer values for the constructor is trivial, but im wondering if there is anyway to use the "texture_menu_label_1" String from the file to reference a pre-existing variable by the same name...

Is there anyway to do this without manually constructing a lookup table?

Comment: This would be better implemented using a multi-dimensional array: quicker, safer, easier to maintain, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't want to do this.  I know you think you do, I remember when I was learning how to program and I thought the same thing, but really, you don't.

There are better ways to store a collection values, in your case, this would be a multi-dimensional array (or a `List<List<int>>`).  If not that, then perhaps a hash table (`Dictionary<string,int[]>`).

Better yet, if this data is 'regular' and logically connected, create your own custom type and maintain a collection of those.  You really don't want to go down the road of tying your logic to the names of your variables... very messy.

That data looks like a rectangle.  Why not just maintain a `Dictionary<string,Rectangle>`?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Rectangle>();
dict.Add("some_name", new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512));
// ... later
var rect = dict["some_name"];  // get the rectangle that maps to "some_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you try to implement an answer please consider why you are doing this, and whether there may be a better solution.

I recommend using a Dictionary to store the data by name as strings.

```
dataDictionary["texture_menu_label_1"] = new int[] { ... };
```

Another approach is to use a separate class with fields, since fields can be accessed by name. You may experience performance issues though, and it's definitely not an optimal solution.

```
class Data
{
    public int[] texture_menu_label_1;
    ...
}
```

You can use reflection to set the field value. Something like this:

```
typeof(Data).GetField("texture_menu_label_1").SetValue(data, new int [] { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashTable (Dictionary for generics) or similar. The key would be the string (texture_menu_label_1) and the value would be the array.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wrap it up in a struct?

```
struct TextureMenu
{
  string MenuString;
  int[] Values;
}
```

Then, instead of dealing directly with either type, you just deal with the struct.